# What's the difference between (Have you) & (Haven't you)?

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences, and when do I use each:

- Have you read the book yet?
- Haven't you read the book yet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purely in terms of a request for information, there is no difference between the two—the answer will produce knowledge of the fact if the book has been read.

However, there is a difference in the emotional tenor and context between the two.

---

> 1. Have you read the book yet?

Generally speaking, this is more of a neutral expression that is simply asking for information.

> A week later, Jim met Jane again. "Have you read the book yet?" he asked her.

---

> 2. Haven't you read the book yet?

This would more often be used in the context of surprise—or even a negative emotion like condescension—and would probably be rhetorical, in the sense that it's already *known* they haven't read it yet, so no response is actually required.

> Two months later, Jane casually told Jim, "I still don't know if she dies in the end."
>   Jim replied in shock, "Haven't you read the book yet?"

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is very clear to me now.